How to replace varactor diode with common diode and capacitor?
I need a variable capacitor for my RF circuit. What I have done so far, I measured the capacitance of 1N4148 which gives me about 20pF. I have configured the following circuit below. I intended to replace a varactor diode with a common diode 1N4148 and a capacitor 68pF in parallel.
When I change the DC voltage from 0V to 12V, the measured value of the diode is getting very high at a range of 100uF and 500uF above. But I need a value in a range of 100's of pF.
Is the measurement realistic, I suppose so. What can be done to get this pF range?
Edit:
What I have not done, is soldering the capacitor in series with 1N4148. Is this the reason? I hope so.


Have you tried removing the diode and seeing what readings you get on your LCR meter when you alter the DC bias voltage.

No, I have not yet. Should I ?

It can't hurt can it? More information = closer to understanding.

Okay, I will try it now. My soldering gun is cold, sniff. It might take several minutes to get hot. I hope you will not miss me for a while..

Diode C  and leakage DC current increases with max. current rating. Varactors are tiny and more consistent with different PIV to compress the 30V typical range to a lower value.  The C ratio can be increased by NOT having any parallel fixed cap or reduced by putting one in series.  The real issue is what range of C do you need but it might not be practical.

Aside from leaving out a series capacitor and thus fooling your capacitance meter, the 1N4148 is rather ill-suited to making a relatively high capacitance varactor.
Here is the typical capacitance vs. reverse bias voltage from a Fairchild/onsemi datasheet:

With only +/-0.125pF variation from 1v to 12V, your capacitance will be dominated by the parallel capacitor and its vagaries.
A relatively large diode such as the 1N400x series would be better suited. You can see the difference in construction between the higher voltage rated types and the lower voltage, a difference that may nor may not be present in similar parts made by current manufacturers.

You can also consider the BB910 type of varactor mentioned by @colintd in a comment, various distributors list diodes designed for use as varactors, and many are fairly inexpensive.

Varactor diodes with a large C tuning ratio are extinct as much as vacuum tubes.
If this is just for a pet project, you can choose a variety of Si diodes with the right characteristics for your design;
e.g. Cmax:min vs Vmax:min
5:1 C-ratio is common,
10:1 C-ratio is rare and
30:1 C-ratios are obsolete
unless you look for a while in surplus sites.
e.g. https://services.taiwansemi.com/storage/resources/datasheet/UF1DLWH%20SERIES_A2103.pdf

Diode C and leakage DC current tend to increase with max. current rating. Schottky diodes are noisy, while Varactors are tiny RF diodes and more consistent C-ratios with different PIV to compress the 30V typical range to a lower value. The C ratio can be increased by NOT having any parallel fixed cap or reduced by putting one in series. The real issue is what range of C do you need but it might not be practical.
In volume, we bought varactors and designed a test set to bin each diode in 10x 1% bins as tolerances are generally pretty loose for C ratios and nominal values. We used it to create a 1ppm TCXO from a 25 cent 1MHz Crystal with C-V values in uC tables and PLL to synthesize 928 MHz 8 kHz channels.

I've had luck in the past with Chinese BB910 vacators.  25:1 not uncommon.  However, haven't used for well over a decade

yah Philips doesn't make them anymore

Digikey has hundreds of p/ns obsolete except the low C-ratio ones

If you want hundreds of pF, consider using a Zener intended for
higher breakdown than your 12V control; the  conductance is high,
the cross sectional area is large, and the depletion region
is thin, so the typical capacitances DO have that range.
OnSemi has notes on this; see figure 23 here especially
Since it isn't a specified property, some batch-buy and sorting
of candidates may be required.
